# Где ошибка в этом коде?(создание вектора куч)

Tags: c++, vector, очередь

```
vector<priority_queue <int> > vect(m, priority_queue <int>);
```

Компилятор ругается

> error: expected primary-expression before ')' token

Comment: Вы не пробовали заодно объявить, например, переменную `a` как `int a(int)`?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или объявите

```
vector<priority_queue <int> > vect(m);
```

или таки определите эту очередь, если очередь по умолчанию вас не устраивает - но не пытайтесь использовать **тип** как **значение**...